# A Question about Irreducible Polynomials

Tags: finite-field

I am doing some self-study in the area of Cryptography. I am using the
Third Edition of the book "Cryptography Theory and Practice" by Douglas  R.
Stinson. Based upon the information on page 105, in the field $F_{2^8}$, I
believe the following two polynomials are multiplicative inverses.

$x^6 + x^4 + x + 1$
$x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x$

If they are and I multiply them together, I should get the irreducible
polynomial for the field right? Here is what I get when I multiply the
two polynomials together in $F_{2^8}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    (x^6)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) + \\
    && (x^4)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) \\
    &+& (x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    (x^{13} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7) + \\
    && (x^{11} + x^{10} + x^7 + x^5) \\
   &+& (x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    (x^{13} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7) + \\
    && (x^{11} + x^{10} + x^7 + x^5) + \\
    && (x^8 + x^7 + x^4 + x^2) + (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    x^{13} + x^{12} + x^{11} + x^9 + x^{10} + x^5 + \\
    && x^8 + x^7 + x^4 + x^2 + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=& x^{13} + x^{12} + x^{11} + \\
    && x^{10} + x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x^9 + x^8 + x^6 + x^3 + x \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=&
    x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + x^8 + x^6 + x^3 + x \\
(x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x) &=& x^8 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
This is not the irreducible polynomial. What am I missing?

Thanks

Bob

Comment: You are not correctly reducing the polynomial after multiplication. To get a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$ from one with terms of degree of eight or more you have to divide it by the irreducible polynomial (you can't just mod 8 the terms degrees).

Comment: You have reduce the polynomial in step 6 using  "long division modulo 2" as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field).

Comment: *"If they are and I multiply them together, I should get the irreducible polynomial for the field right?"* Wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

In the page $104$ you can see:
$$F_{2^8}=\frac{Z_2[x]}{x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1}.$$
this means that irreducible polynomial that generate the $F_{2^8}$ is $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$. so, in multiplications, you should note that $x^8=-x^4-x^3-x-1=x^4+x^3+x+1$. Therefore $x^{8+i}=x^8\cdot x^i=x^{4+i}+x^{3+i}+x^{1+i}+x^i$.